# Is it possible to change the size of the image you get from using the camera thru imagePicker?

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller

When I try to change the property currently, I am getting a error that the size is a "Get Only Property." Anyone know a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following (I didn't run it yet, pretty sure it works..)

```
let imagePickerView: UIView = self.imagePicker.view
let cameraViewFrame: CGRect = CGRectMake(0, self.overlay.topBarHeight, 
                                self.view.bounds.size.width, 
                                self.view.bounds.size.height -self.overlay.topBarHeight - self.overlay.bottomBarHeight);
imagePickerView.frame = cameraViewFrame
```

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

What we can do is to draw a new UIImage instead. The code below is a function to scale the image passed in. And after the image has been scaled, the size changes.

```
extension UIImage {
    class func scaleImage(image:UIImage, scaleFloat:CGFloat) -> UIImage{
            let size = CGSizeMake(image.size.width * scaleFloat, image.size.height * scaleFloat)
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
            let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
            var transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, scaleFloat, scaleFloat)
            CGContextConcatCTM(context, transform)
            image.drawAtPoint(CGPointMake(0, 0))
            let newimg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            return newimg
        }
}
```

Here is the example code to scale the image to 150x150. But these codes only helps the square image. If it is not square, you can test for what will happen.

```
extension UIImage {
    class func scaleImgTo150x150(image:UIImage) -> UIImage{
            let scale:CGFloat
            if image.size.width > image.size.height{
                scale = 150/image.size.width
            }
            else{
                scale = 150/image.size.height
            }
            return UIImage.scaleImage(image, scaleFloat: scale)
        }
}
```